# searchTwitter cannot connect to host

Tags: r, twitter, rstudio

I am using the twitteR package in R and when I try to use the searchTwitter function I get this message:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
```

The weird thing is that I only get this message in RStudio.  If I do the same directly in R, it works fine.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: There is a difference between incoming and outgoing traffic. Your it department might very well allow you to download some files, but disallow making connections to the outside on certain ports. Therefore, I would have a talk with your it department first.

Comment: Have you performed all the necessary authentication & handshake? Could you show us the code you are using?

Comment: Thank you both, here's the code: > library(twitteR)
Loading required package: RCurl
Loading required package: bitops
Loading required package: rjson
> searchTwitter("Gaga", n=10)
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host

Answer (score 0):

Done! There was a missing file (.Renviron) with the proxy configuration.